# How to better understand the code/statements from "Async - Handling multiple Exceptions" article?

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await, async-ctp

Running the following C# console app

```
class Program
{  static void Main(string[] args)
   {  Tst();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
   async static Task  Tst()
   {
       try
       {
           await Task.Factory.StartNew
             (() =>
                {
                   Task.Factory.StartNew
                       (() =>
                         { throw new NullReferenceException(); }
                         , TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
                        );
               Task.Factory.StartNew
                       (  () =>
                               { throw new ArgumentException(); }
                               ,TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
                       );
                }
             );
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        // this catch will never be target
        Console.WriteLine("** {0} **", ex.GetType().Name);

//******  Update1 - Start of Added code
        foreach (var exc in ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(exc.GetType().Name);
        }
//******  Update1 - End of Added code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("## {0} ##", ex.GetType().Name);
    }
 }
```

produces the output:

```
** AggregateException **
```

Though, the code above is reproducing the first snippet from  ["Async - Handling multiple Exceptions"](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2012/12/10/async-handling-multiple-exceptions.aspx) blog article, which tells about it :

> the following code will catch a single NullReferenceException or
>   ArgumentException exception (the AggregateException will be ignored)

Where is the problem:

1. the article is wrong?
   Which code/statements and how to change in order to correctly understand it?
2. I made an error in reproducing the first code snippet of the article?
3. It is due to a bug in .NET 4.0/VS2010  Async CTP  extension, I am using?

### Update1 (in response to [svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571791/how-to-better-understand-the-code-statements-from-async-handling-multiple-exc/16572968#16572968))

Upon adding the code

```
//******  Update1 - Start of Added code
        foreach (var exc in ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(exc.GetType().Name);
        }
//******  Update1 - End of Added code
```

the produced output is:

```
** AggregateException **
NullReferenceException
```

So, as also [commented Matt Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571791/how-to-better-understand-the-code-statements-from-async-handling-multiple-exc#comment23813945_16572968):

> the `AggregateException` that is caught, contains only one of the
>   exceptions that was thrown (either the `NullReferenceException` or the
>   `ArgumentException` depending on the order of execution of the child
>   Tasks)

Most probably, the article is still <s>correct or, at least,</s> very useful. I just need to understand how to better read/understand/use it

### Update2 (in response to [svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571791/how-to-better-understand-the-code-statements-from-async-handling-multiple-exc/16572968#16572968))

Executing svick's code:

```
internal class Program
{
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Tst();
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  private static async Task Tst()
  {
    try
    {
      await TaskEx.WhenAll
        (
          Task.Factory.StartNew
            (() =>
               { throw new NullReferenceException(); }
            //, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
            ),
          Task.Factory.StartNew
            (() =>
               { throw new ArgumentException(); }
            //,TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
            )

        );
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
      // this catch will never be target
      Console.WriteLine("** {0} **", ex.GetType().Name);

      //******  Update1 - Start of Added code
      foreach (var exc in ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("==="+exc.GetType().Name);
      }
      //******  Update1 - End of Added code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("## {0} ##", ex.GetType().Name);
    }
  }
}
```

produces:

```
## NullReferenceException ##
```

output.

Why isn't `AggregateException` produced or caught?

Comment: I see the same results with VS2012 and .Net4.5. I'm pretty sure the article is just wrong. Using `AttachedToParent` means that exceptions will be automatically propogated (even without an `await`, `Wait()`, `.Result` call) but the parent `Task` will still throw an `AggregateException` whose inner exception(s) correspond to the actual exception(s) thrown.

Comment: @dlev , thanks. Could you copy-paste your comment into the answer section? I am thinking to post the question about differences of exceptions propagation between child and detached nested tasks

Comment: Note, dlev's comment is slightly misleading:  If you do `Wait` or `Result` you'll get the outer `AggregateException` which does contain all the exceptions.  If you do `await`, you'll get one of the inner `AggregateException`s which represents the exceptions thrown by only *one* of the child `Task`s.

Comment: @MattSmith, I'd appreciate if you put your comments as the answer

Comment: #dlev, just checked after exiting from my hibernation (sleeping) -without `await` no exception is caught (but with `await` only 1 of 2 is caught)

Comment: @Геннадий-Ванин, my comment was after svick's answer was posted (which I think is the correct answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article is wrong. When you run your code, the `await`ed `Task` contains an exception that looks something like this:

```
AggregateException
  AggregateException
    NullReferenceException
  AggregateException
    ArgumentException
```

What `await` (or, more specifically, [`TaskAwaiter.GetResult()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult.aspx)) does here is that it takes the outer `AggregateException` and rethrows its first child exception. Here, that's another `AggregateException`, so that's what is thrown.

Example of code where a `Task` has multiple exceptions and one of them is directly rethrown after `await` would be to use `Task.WhenAll()` instead of `AttachedToParent`:

```
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new NullReferenceException(); }),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new ArgumentException(); }));
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    // this catch will never be target
    Console.WriteLine("** {0} **", ex.GetType().Name);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("## {0} ##", ex.GetType().Name);
}
```

Comment: +1, To highlight: the `AggregateException` that is caught, contains only *one* of the exceptions that was thrown (either the `NullReferenceException` or the `ArgumentException` depending on the order of execution of the child `Tasks`)

Comment: @svick , your starting statements are not correct (see Update1 in my question) and I have very-very bad idiosyncrasy of not proceeding further until I understand how to correct the wrong or correctly / better understand (disambiguate) incorrect statements (and why they were at all and what they were supposed to convey)

Comment: @MattSmith, it is independendent on " on the order of execution of the child Tasks" but what I have the difficulty to grasp [why only one exception from child tasks always propagated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580125/why-is-only-one-from-many-exceptions-from-child-tasks-always-propagated)

Comment: @Геннадий-Ванин Your update is not in contradiction with my answer. Like I said, the exception that is thrown by `await` is not the outer `AggregateException`, it's first of the inner ones. So, calling `Flatten()` on the caught exception returning only one exception is excepted. But if you save the `Task` into a variable and call `task.Exception.Flatten()`, that will return both exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your "Update 2", the reasoning is still the same as in svick's answer. The task contains an `AggregateException`, but awaiting it throws the first `InnerException`.

The additional information you need is in the Task.WhenAll documentation (emphasis mine):

> If any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state, the returned task will also complete in a Faulted state, where its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of **unwrapped** exceptions from each of the supplied tasks.

So that Task's exceptions will look like:

```
AggregateException 
    NullReferenceException 
    ArgumentException
```

Comment: So, why then `AggreagateException` is never caught? Are exceptions really wrapped into `AggreagateException` for detached tasks of Update2? The code in `catch (AggregateException ex){} `is never entered. The exception is caught only in second `catch (Exception ex) {}` block (and without it, is lost)

Comment: Because the AggregateException is never thrown.  When a task ends up in the faulted state, using `await` on it will do the following:
1. Get the Task's `AggregateException` (it is always an `AggregateException`)
2. take the first `InnerException` and throw it.