# How to get all exceptions from all nested tasks of async/awaited parent?

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

Re-using slightly modified code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16584469/2031316), how to modify it in order to implement [@svick's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571791/how-to-better-understand-the-code-statements-from-async-handling-multiple-exc/16572968#comment23837031_16572968):

> But if you save the Task into a variable and call
>   task.Exception.Flatten(), that will return both exceptions

?

```
//C# console app
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Test();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
    async static Task Test()
    {
      Task containingTask, nullRefTask, argTask;
      try
      {
        containingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew
          (() =>
              {
                nullRefTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException();
                }
                , TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

                argTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                }
                , TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
              }
           );
        await containingTask;
        foreach(Exception ex in containingTask.Exception
                                              .Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        //Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'
        { //never entered
            Console.WriteLine("@@@@@"+ex.GetType().Name);
        } 
      }//try
      catch (AggregateException ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("** {0} **", ex.GetType().Name);
        foreach (var exc in ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("$$$$$$"+exc.GetType().Name);
        }

//foreach (Exception exxx in containingTask.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
//Use of unassigned local variable 'containingTask' 
      }
//foreach (Exception exxx in containingTask.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
////Use of unassigned local variable 'containingTask'   
    }
  }
```

When I am trying to access `containingTask.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions`  with or without using try-/catch-blocks, in  or out of `try`-, `catch`-blocks, produces errors:

```
Use of unassigned local variable 'containingTask'
```

or

```
Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

How to see/get both exceptions from both child tasks?

### Update:

This part was removed from question since, after correcting a typo, the code produces expected results

<s>**Variant #2 (C# console app):**

Trying to reproduce the "workaround" from ["Async - Handling multiple Exceptions"](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2012/12/10/async-handling-multiple-exceptions.aspx) to see all exceptions from all child tasks:</s>

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tst();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    async static Task Tst()
    {
        try
        {
            Task t= Task.Factory.StartNew
                (
                    () =>
                       {
                           Task.Factory.StartNew
                           (
                               () =>
                                  { throw new NullReferenceException(); }
                               ,TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
                           );
                           Task.Factory.StartNew
                           (
                               () =>
                                   { throw new ArgumentException(); }
                                   , TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
                           );
                       }
                );
            await t.ContinueWith
                    (
                        tsk =>
                          {
                              if (tsk.Exception != null)
                                   throw tsk.Exception;
                           }
                    );
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var exc in ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("** {0} **", exc.GetType().Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("## {0} ##", ex.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first `AggregateException` (from the original task) becomes wrapped in a second `AggregateException` (from the continued task) and so you actually need to call `Flatten()` twice to get to the inner exceptions you want.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the Variant2. There was a stupid typo. After correcting it, Variant2 started to output expected results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Task`s or `async`-`await`. If you simplify your code to the following one, you will still get the same error:

```
string s;
try
{
    s = "something";
}
catch (SomeException)
{
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

The compiler assumes that there might be an exception thrown inside the `try` but before the assignment is executed and so you get this error. Why does the compiler assume that? Because it can actually happen: `ThreadAbortException` can be thrown at pretty much any point. And the rules about definite assignment don't try to be too clever to know what are the rules where a specific exception can be thrown.

To fix this, assign `null` (or another default value) to the variable.